# Qual a diferença entre os termos X.509 e PKCS#7 em certificados digitais?

Tags: c#, .net, segurança, criptografia, tls

Via uma WebApi .Net 4.6.1 eu estou fazendo a integração com um serviço que exige que os dados sejam enviados em uma conexão `TLS 1.2` devidamente assinados digitalmente utilizando o padrão **`PKCS#7`**, mas ao verificar [um exemplo de integração](https://github.com/hgmauri/registro-boleto-online-bradesco), percebi que a implementação faz uso da classe `X509Certificate2`, e que o **`X.509`** também é um padrão de certificado.

**1.** Afinal, se ambos são padrões, usar a classe `X509Certificate2` é um equivoco para implementar com base no `PKCS#7`?

**2.** Em conexões TLS o envio do certificado não deveria ser feito apenas uma vez no Handshake TLS e posteriormente a todas as validações ser trocada a chave simétrica compartilha para então sim começar o envio dos dados de maneira segura?

**2.1.** Nesse caso me parece que os dados já estão sendo assinados e enviados com a chave assimétrica privada para então sim serem descriptografados com a pública no servidor de destino. Ou por detrás dos panos o próprio `.Net` gerencia todo o processo necessário para concluir a conexão TLS corretamente até gerar a chave simétrica?

Comment: X509 define o formato dos certificados digitais, e PKCS7 define a assinatura digital. Tecnicamente, assina-se com a chave privada (mas o certificado só tem a chave pública), mas costuma-se dizer que "assinou com o certificado" quando a chave privada correspondente à chave pública do certificado foi usada. Não sei se é assim no .NET (não programo em C#), mas algumas APIs inclusive fazem com que a chave privada seja acessada pelo certificado mesmo. Dito isso, o ponto 1 não me parece equivocado